# How to get set of key value pairs from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a class called Student:
It has property called _ClassValues. It's basically an IEnumerable of string key value pair with values like:

```
Student._ClassValues[0, 0] = "Class1"
Student._ClassValues[0, 1] = "Class2"
Student._ClassValues[0, 2] = "Class2"
Student._ClassValues[0, 3] = "Class1"
... So on.. 
Student._ClassValues[1, 1] = "Exam1"
Student._ClassValues[1, 2] = "Exam2"
Student._ClassValues[1, 3] = "Exam1"
... So on..
```

Is there an easier way to get all _ClassValues which contain string "Class1"?

I created lot of methods to get these values, but I know there got to be a better way of doing this, is there?

Comment: It seems to me that a better solution would be to avoid using this structure to start with - instead have a `List<T>` for some suitable "class and exam" pairing.

Comment: I think there are some structure issues here. Maybe consider a Dictionary<Class, List<Exam>>... hard to infer exactly what your goal is though.

Comment: @JonSkeet - There are more than Class and exam in that list. It is pretty long list that is the reason i used ienumerable.

Comment: Then that's an even *better* reason to use a custom type - something that ties together all the different values in one object.

Comment: What are you trying to model with your IEnumerable collection? To me, it looks like a schedule for a student where the two-dimensional array provides access to lessons etc. for a certain day (day of week) and hour...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using a multi-dimensional array - that's still not an appropriate approach, IMO. You've always got the class at position 0, the exam at position 1 etc, right? So encapsulate those in a class. Why do you *want* to use a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @JonSkeet - No it can change Class will not always be at 0.

Comment: @Gurnor Please explain the problem domain you are trying to model. Then, we may find a matchhing data structure and _then_ we may find efficient functionality.

Comment: @helb - I think i am explaining it wrong or not able to explain it, i am sorry! But it will really help me if someone can tell me. How to get particular values from a string array (string [,]). How can i get all values which contain text as "Class1"? Thanks! Or should i create another questions, that be better to explain?

Comment: @helb - Thanks is it possilbe to get index of first Class1 values, rather than going through the loop?

Comment: @Gurnor I see now what you want. Check my new answer.

Comment: @Gurnor: Our point is that using a string array like this is almost certainly the wrong approach to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> FindString(string[,] values, string search)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (values[i, j] == search)
            {
                result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var positions = FindString(Student._ClassValues, "Class1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all values in the two-dimensional array using a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach (string value in Student._ClassValues)
{
    if (value == "Class1")
    { 
        // do something
    }
}
```